# Create pages like tiles using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a pages like **tiles** in my homepages. if i click that **tiles** it will redirect or **popup** the related content of the page... how to create that?

Anyone please give me some **jquery** plugins or **css** anything to do this?

I attach image here,

[image]

Comment: Good luck, please come back when you got some code to share.

Comment: I doubt you even need a plugin to do this as it seems quite basic from your description. Try to attempt it first then come and ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: for every time i first search in google then only will ask questions. generally i can't find out the plugin. i edit my question. please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that for a starting point?

```
<div class="tile"> Tile 1 </div>
<div class="tile"> Tile 2 </div>
<div class="tile"> Tile 3 </div>
<div class="tile"> Tile 4 </div>
<div class="tile"> Tile 5 </div>
<div class="tile"> Tile 6 </div>


.tile {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.tile:hover {
    background-color:#bbb;
}


$( ".tile" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

Link:
[tiles with hover and jQuery click-event](http://jsfiddle.net/yH35w/)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

[matrix html tiles](http://billyf.expertvm.com/Matrix/)

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. i edit my question.please see that.